# xml data into mysql insert/update query using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an XML file (cycles.xml) as follows:

```
<cycles>
  <cycle ID="1003" name="some_name" group="00010" department="00060" students="some_students" type="some_type" sertfy="C" specialty="some_specialty" employment="some_employment" quantity="28" datefrom="2018-02-07" dateto="2018-03-07" cost="20000" duration="1.00" /> 
  <cycle ID="1004" name="some_name" group="00010" department="00060" students="some_students" type="some_type" sertfy="C" specialty="some_specialty" employment="some_employment" quantity="28" datefrom="2018-02-27" dateto="2018-03-27" cost="20000" duration="1.00" /> 
</cycles>
```

Here is what my cycles table looks like:

[image: cycles table]

What I am trying to understand is how to add this data into MySQL. Currently I know how to select the XML, but I am lost on how exactly to select my values (name, order, etc). I do not know how to insert this XML data into MySQL.

Comment: PHP has functions to parse XML files, have you tried to find them?

Comment: Yes, Simple XML, DOM, xml_parser (SAX), XMLReader but the problem is that i don't know php well so it;s hard for me to understand all this functions in the right way

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample code.
You can make use of this.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("cycles.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$cycles = $xml->cycle;
foreach($cycles as $cycle){
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO cycles VALUES($cycle->ID,$cycle->name,$cycle->group,$cycle->department,$cycle->students);
    $DB->execute($sql);
}
```

Comment: Thank's, i'll try it

Comment: Maybe u should take care of the syntax correction and database execution as per your framework or custom code while implementing this.